# How do I say WHERE (a=1 and b=1) or (c=1 and d=1)

Tags: php, laravel

How do I say WHERE (a=1 and b=1) or (c=1 and d=1)

For more complicated queries am I supposed to use raw SQL?

Comment: For seriously complicated queries I would use compiled sql, but that's just me. By the way please read on http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL select query with multiple conditions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16249731/mysql-select-query-with-multiple-conditions)

Comment: @syedmohamed I think he wants to express the query with Eloquent, rather than mySql.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325312/laravel-eloquent-multiple-where-clause-query

Answer (score 2):

Try this: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#advanced-where-clauses

```
   DB::table('your_table')
    ->where(function($query)
    {
        $query->where('a', 1) ->where('b', 1);
    })
    ->orWhere(function($query)
    {
        $query->where('c', 1)->where('d', 1);
    })
    ->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

@esmail please try to study then,wrote comment.You can definitely do this like that code

```
->where(function($query)
        {
                $query->where('a', 1)
                ->where('b', 1);
        })
```