# Fetching Data from WordPress Database Using Custom PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

Without using WordPress or writing a plugin based on WordPress, I want to be able to fetch data from WordPress database tables and also insert into it. I will be writing the the code in either procedural or OOP but it's definitely outside of the WordPress framework.

Right now, I am able to fetch from `wp_users` table but trying to join `wp_users` with `wp_usermeta` is not working right. I wanted to display data relating to a particular user in the usermeta table but fetching is a bit difficuly since `wp_usermeta` table uses `meta_key` and `meta_value` to save these data. So, how do you fetch first_name and last_name for a user when table columns are meta_key and meta_value?

Current Query:

```
SELECT a.*, b1.meta_value AS first_name, b1.*, b2.meta_value AS last_name, b2.*
FROM wp_users a
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta b1 ON b1.user_id = a.ID AND b1.meta_key = 'first_name' 
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta b2 ON b2.user_id = a.ID AND b2.meta_key = 'last_name'
WHERE (b1.meta_value LIKE '%_%' OR b2.meta_value LIKE '%_%' OR a.user_email LIKE '%_%')
```

Looping:

```
<tr>
    <td><?= $row['ID']; ?></td>
    <td><?= $row['user_login']; ?></td>
    <td><?= $row['user_email']; ?></td>
    <td><?= $row['first_name']; ?></td>
    <td><?= $row['last_name']; ?></td>
    <td><?= $row['phone']; ?></td>
    <td>
        <?php
        if ( $row['user_id_verified'] == 1 ){
            echo "Yes";
        } else {
            echo "No";
        }
        ?>
    </td>
    <td><?= date('M j, Y h:i A', strtotime($row['user_registered'])); ?></td>
</tr>
```

Output:
[image: Code output]

I have tried using INNER JOIN but the result is not right. I might just have one particular user on two pages (table pagination) before the next user.

I would like every user's data to be on the same row which will also help for updating later.

Comment: Please add into your question what your current queries look like, what output they produce and what output you want it to produce

Comment: I would imagine that WP has some sort of short cut, but it sounds like you need to use [a pivot query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67272841/2943403).

Comment: @JacobMulquin I have done that. Kindly take a look again. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a user ID and you want to retrieve the first_name and last_name for that user, you can use a query like the following:

```
SELECT
  u.ID,
  u.user_login,
  u.user_email,
  MAX(CASE WHEN m.meta_key = 'first_name' THEN m.meta_value END) AS first_name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN m.meta_key = 'last_name' THEN m.meta_value END) AS last_name
FROM
  wp_users u
LEFT JOIN
  wp_usermeta m ON u.ID = m.user_id
WHERE
  u.ID = :user_id
GROUP BY
  u.ID, u.user_login, u.user_email;
```

**To get all information for the user:**
Assuming you have a user ID and you want to retrieve following details:

- ID
- Username
- Email
- First name
- Last name
- Phone
- Roles
- Date

You can use this updated query like the following:

```
SELECT
  u.ID,
  u.user_login AS Username,
  u.user_email AS Email,
  MAX(CASE WHEN m1.meta_key = 'first_name' THEN m1.meta_value END) AS First_name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN m1.meta_key = 'last_name' THEN m1.meta_value END) AS Last_name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN m2.meta_key = 'phone' THEN m2.meta_value END) AS Phone,
  CASE WHEN r.meta_value LIKE '%administrator%' THEN 'Administrator'
       WHEN r.meta_value LIKE '%editor%' THEN 'Editor'
       WHEN r.meta_value LIKE '%author%' THEN 'Author'
       WHEN r.meta_value LIKE '%contributor%' THEN 'Contributor'
       WHEN r.meta_value LIKE '%subscriber%' THEN 'Subscriber'
       ELSE 'Unknown'
  END AS Status,
  u.user_registered AS Date
FROM
  wp_users u
LEFT JOIN
  wp_usermeta m1 ON u.ID = m1.user_id
LEFT JOIN
  wp_usermeta m2 ON u.ID = m2.user_id
LEFT JOIN
  wp_usermeta r ON u.ID = r.user_id AND r.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities'
WHERE
  u.ID = :user_id
GROUP BY
  u.ID, u.user_login, u.user_email, u.user_registered;
```

**Note:** Replace **':user_id'** with the actual user ID you want to fetch data for. Also, ensure that you have the **correct table prefix** in your queries, as it may vary based on your WordPress installation.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll need this code later but I'd like to retrieve everything for all users. How do I go about that? Not just `first_name` and `last_name` but for other user info located inside the `wp_usermeta` table.

Comment: @I.Am.That.JUDE, I have updated my response according to your comment to retrieve all the information as you requested. Please check and let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score -1):

To fetch `first_name` and `last_name` for a user from the WordPress database tables `wp_users` and `wp_usermeta`, you need to perform a SQL query that joins these tables correctly. Since the `wp_usermeta` table stores user metadata using `meta_key` and `meta_value` columns, you'll need to use a conditional join to fetch the specific `meta_value` for `first_name` and `last_name` related to a particular user.

Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

```sql
SELECT u.ID, u.user_login, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN um1.meta_key = 'first_name' THEN um1.meta_value END) AS first_name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN um1.meta_key = 'last_name' THEN um1.meta_value END) AS last_name
FROM wp_users u
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta um1 ON u.ID = um1.user_id
WHERE um1.meta_key IN ('first_name', 'last_name')
GROUP BY u.ID, u.user_login;
```

Explanation:

1. We start with the `wp_users` table (`u`) and use a LEFT JOIN to connect it with the `wp_usermeta` table (`um1`) using the `user_id` as the common field.
2. In the SELECT statement, we use conditional aggregation (MAX with CASE statements) to fetch the `meta_value` for `first_name` and `last_name` based on the `meta_key`.
3. We use a WHERE clause to filter the rows in `wp_usermeta` where `meta_key` is either 'first_name' or 'last_name'.
4. Finally, we GROUP BY `ID` and `user_login` from the `wp_users` table to ensure that each user's data is on the same row.

This query will return a result set with one row for each user, with their `first_name` and `last_name` displayed as separate columns.

You can use this SQL query within your PHP code (either procedural or OOP) to fetch the data from the WordPress database without relying on the WordPress framework.

Comment: Did you create this answer with [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1)?

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll try it out. But how do I fetch other details (everything related to each user) from the `wp_usermeta` table and not just `first_name` and `last_name`?